# How can I stop the side launcher from autohiding?

Tags: 11.10, menu, gui

How can I get the side menu on my left to stay in place?

And since it's going to stay in place, how can I ensure my application windows don't get hidden (in part) by the menu (ie: their width should be my horizontal resolution - width of  the menu)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First, install the compizconfig-settings-manager package.
- Open the Unity dash and search for "ccsm". Open the Compiz Config Settings Manager result.
- In CCSM's filter box, type "unity".
- Click the Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Change Hide Launcher to Never.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [these instructions](http://peterpants.blogspot.com/2011/04/ubuntu-1104-unity-how-to-disable-unity.html). They were written for Natty but should apply to Oneiric as well. The page has useful screenshots.

This is the same procedure as [Azendale's good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/66916/22949), presented differently. In summary, in case both the linked page and that answer become unavailable:

- Install `compizconfig-settings-manager`.
- In System Settings, open CompizConfig Settings Manager.
- Go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin (you can search for *unity* to find it).
- Behavior tab → Hide Launcher → **Never**.

Your application windows should not be hidden by the menu--it will simply be as though they have less screen space to occupy.